# Creating an array of arrays for GD::Graph

Tags: arrays, perl, gd-graph

All right, I'm trying to make an array of arrays in Perl for use with the GD::Graph module. And I can't figure out why the following is not valid array of arrays for GD::Graph.

```
my @t = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @g = (2, 4, 5, 6);
my @data = (@t, @g);
```

I've also tried constructing the data like below, and it still does not like it.

```
my @data;
push @data, @t;
push @data, @g;
```

I want to keep my values in seperate arrays and just combine them for use with GD::Graph, because that is what I've found to be the easiest way, even if it is ugly. How would I go about creating a valid structure for use with GD::Graph, that is created on the fly?

It complains about it here.

```
my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like @data is just a single dimension array with 8 elements.

You can define array of arrays by using the anonymous array constructor []

```
my @data = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 4, 5, 6]
);
```

Comment: I've seen that done before. However I am interested in combining multiple array variables into an array of arrays. I tried applying `my @data = ([@t],[@g]);` and it still does not like it.

Comment: OK, instead of the array constructor, you can use references.  @data = (\@t, \@g);

Comment: The references worked. Also I had the `graph->plot` line wrong. I needed to use references there too.

Answer (score 0):

For me using array references did the trick

```
my @t = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @g = (2, 4, 5, 6);
my @data = (\@t, \@g);
```

and the plot the chart with fro example:

```
my $graph = new GD::Graph::lines(800,600 );
my $gd = $graph->plot( \@data );
open OUT, ">","whatever.png" or die "Couldn't open for output: $!";
binmode(OUT);
print OUT $gd->png( );
close OUT;
```

Comment: Here's why: Perl 4 didn't have references, nor lists in lists, so it flattened all lists: `(@t, @g)` was the concatenation of `@t` and `@g`; obviously it would have broken a lot of code if Perl 5 had changed this.